# What is the difference between dispersion and differential mode group delay?

Tags: optics, fiber-optics

I want to know what exactly is the [differential mode group delay](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=differential+mode+group+delay) in optical fibers, is it the same thing as [dispersion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_%28optics%29)?